# Amazon cognito login failure : SRP error in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to login using Amazon Cognito in Android. The credentials - username and password are valid but i get the below error

> com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.exceptions.CognitoInternalErrorException: SRP error
>
> > cause = java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

The Amazon Cognito user registration (signup) and verification works cool! but I'm not able to get through the login flow due to the above error.

Any help on this will be a great rescue :) TIA!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. In my case it was wrong **Pool Id**.

Please check **Pool Id**. You are able to sign up new user if **Pool Id** is invalid, however you can't do user authentication.

Comment: The same mistake I have done, the pool id was incorrect! Thanks a lot i spent a whole day looking at the issue but not getting any clue on it...